# Is there a switch to get the default values of a SQL Server's table's fields as default values for TextBoxes of a FormView / DetailsView?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2 and VS2010 C# ASP.NET 4

FormView and DetailsView comes empty TextBoxes in Insert mode.

I would like those TextBoxes to reflect the default values from the respective columns' defaults on the SQL Server.

Is there a simple way to do that?

---

Edited: (example)

The question:

[image]

The table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SampleTable](
    [PKColumn1] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    [IntColumn2] [int] NOT NULL DEFAULT (12),
    [nvarcharColumn3] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL DEFAULT (N'bla bla'),
    [IntColumn4NoDefault] [int] NULL)
```

The aspx markup:

```
<asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" Height="50px" Width="125px" 
            AutoGenerateRows="False" DataKeyNames="PKColumn1" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
            DefaultMode="Insert">
            <Fields>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="PKColumn1" HeaderText="PKColumn1" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="PKColumn1" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="IntColumn2" HeaderText="IntColumn2" SortExpression="IntColumn2" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="nvarcharColumn3" HeaderText="nvarcharColumn3" SortExpression="nvarcharColumn3" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="IntColumn4NoDefault" 
                    HeaderText="IntColumn4NoDefault" SortExpression="IntColumn4NoDefault" />
                <asp:CommandField ShowInsertButton="True" />
            </Fields>
        </asp:DetailsView>

        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:dbConnectionString %>" 
            InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [SampleTable] ([IntColumn2], [nvarcharColumn3], [IntColumn4NoDefault]) VALUES (@IntColumn2, @nvarcharColumn3, @IntColumn4NoDefault)" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [SampleTable]">
            <InsertParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="IntColumn2" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="nvarcharColumn3" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="IntColumn4NoDefault" Type="Int32" />
            </InsertParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Nothing in C# code behind.

Comment: It resides in information_schema tables. I forgot which one

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is...

```
select  c.name, definition 
from    sys.default_constraints dc 
join    sys.columns c 
on      c.object_id = dc.parent_object_id 
        and c.column_id = dc.parent_column_id 
where   parent_object_id = object_id('mytable')
```

Once you get your resultset back, you should have the column name and default value.  If each column with a default value corresponds (1:1) to a textbox, simply add a Repeater to your form/webform and bind 'definition' to the Text property.  You might have to massage the data a bit due to the added parentheses in the output, but possibly a regular expression or a simple replace might do the trick.

Comment: chris-gessler - So, there is no simple solution for the normal situation, in which some columns does not have a default value.

Comment: @Different111222 - the simple solution would be to use a RIGHT JOIN